# Custom Elements Illegal Constructor in FireFox

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-component, polyfills, custom-element

I have a CustomElement with the following constructor:

```
export default class SomeCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(templateId) {
        super();
        this.insertTemplateInstance(templateId);
    }
    ...
}
```

I can register that Element in Chrome without any Problems.

But using Firefox with the polyfill loaded by `webcomponents-loader.js` from https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs I get the ErrorMessage `TypeError: Illegal constructor` when calling `super()`.

Does anybody know what is causing this?

Some more Background:

Registering of the custom Elements happens like this:

```
window.addEventListener("WebComponentsReady", function () {
    customElements.define(elementName, SomeCustomElement);
});
```

Comment: no. But I'm using rollup to be able to use es2015 modules / imports

Comment: You should try with webcomponents-lite. Here the error suggests that the polyfill is not loaded yet when the element is instanciated. Also, you should not call customElement.define in the WebComponentsReady callback.

Comment: where should i call define then? I thought calling it in WebComponentsReady would ensure that it is called after the polyfill has been loaded completely

Comment: After having loaded the polyfill, or in the imported file (with <link>). WebComponentReady ensures that the component is already defined and intanciated in order to invoke its methods.

Comment: How do I know that the polyfill has been loaded? Is there another event for that?

Comment: The polyfill should be loaded synchronously. I've tested it with webcomponents-lite and it works fine with firefox. No event needed. Just put the <script> tag before your custom elements tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `webcomponents-lite.js` instead of `webcomponent-loader.js` if you don't want to have this kind of error, which is caused by the fact that the polyfills will be loaded asynchronously if you use `webcomponents-loader.js`.

The example below works fine with Firefox (and every modern browser):

```js
class SomeCustomElement extends HTMLElement
{
  constructor()
  {
    console.log( 'created' )
    super()
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log( 'connected' )
    this.innerHTML = "Hello"
  }
}

customElements.define( 'c-e', SomeCustomElement )
```

```html
<script src=https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents-lite.js></script>

<c-e></c-e>
```

However if you still want to use `webcomponents-loader.js`, you'll have to insert your custom element definition in an external file, and load it with HTML Imports:

```
<link rel="import" href="my-element.html">
```

Comment: Does not work in FF 56, 57 on linux, Nov. 2017. Throws on the call to `super` because of trying to directly call `HTMLElement` as a constructor.

Comment: Do you have the flag set in `about:config`? Also what OS? Haven't tried anything but linux yet.

Comment: @JaredSmith no it should be unset, it's not compliant with Custom Elements v1. Use polyfill only.

Comment: I don't have it set either, still get the error with polyfill files. Still throws on call to super. Just tested FF 54 on OSX High Sierra, same problem.

Comment: Nevermind, figured problem out from reading your comments on the original question. Had the file before the polyfill and tried to register in the `WebComponentsReady` listener. They really need better documentation for all of this (although I realize its tough to keep it updated for something being actively developed).

Answer (score 0):

Caveat upfront: I'm not a huge fan of html imports. I stumbled across this trying to get ES 6 class-based custom elements to work in Firefox. For a conditional-polyfill-loading-no-html-import solution based on the accepted answer, read on...

To conditionally load the polyfills gets a little tricky. Per @Supersharp's answer/comments, for some reason the polyfill *must* be loaded synchronously (despite there being no mention of this in the official documentation). So now you have two unappealing options: include it unconditionally to get the necessary synchronous loading or...use `document.write`:

```
<script>
;(function() {
  var str = '';
  // You could make this more fine-grained if desired by doing
  // more feature detection and loading the minimal polyfill file 
  if (!window.customElements) str += '<script src="./node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>';
  str += '<script src="./elements.js"></script>';
  document.write(str);
})();
</script>
<foo-bar></foo-bar>
```

Then in `elements.js`:

```
class FooBar extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    console.log("constructing");
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback () {
    console.log("connecting");
  }

  disconnectedCallback () {
    console.log("disconnecting");
  }
};
// Note that because of the synchronous loading we don't
// need to listen for the event
customElements.define('foo-bar', FooBar);
```

`document.write` is widely disliked for good reasons but this is IMHO a legitimate use case. Note that most of the objections here (no pre-fetch, etc.) can be ameliorated through use of service workers (for browsers that support them).